# Sidebar broken on wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, coding-style, sidebar

On my shop page the sidebar is working fine but on the wcfm marketplace store page the sidebar is covering the page. its the mobile view.

the shop page is here 
https://melaninmart.com/shop/

the store page is here
https://melaninmart.com/store/lustablesz-cosmetics/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question appears to be too broad. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS, specifically these 3 attributes:

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
.sidebar {
    top: 0;
    max-width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Position:fixed and top:0 means your sidebar is forced to stick to the top of the page element, where on a mobile-view, you want the sidebar to stack above or below the content.

Changing this code to the following fixes the issue:

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
.sidebar {
    top: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked. is there a way to add it to a drop down menu at the top of the store

Comment: can i make it stack above content but bretract into dropdown menu?

Comment: No problem Johnny. Please upvote and accept my answer to show it resolved your original issue. The easiest way to implement the sidebar as a dropdown menu would be to create it as a menu (in Appearance / Menus) and then implemented it in your theme. Your theme will have the functionality built in to implement the menu as an expanding mobile menu.